# XQuery: How to check if two attributes have the same value?

Tags: mysql, xml, xquery

Suppose I have two elements like the following:

(Teacher name='John' age='25') and (Student name='John' age='30)

And I want to find out which students have the same name as one of the teachers but are also older than the teacher.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for $teacher in //$Teacher
    where $teacher/@name = //$Student/@name 
    return
    if (  $teacher/@age < //$Student/@age) then

          ($teacher/@name)
    else()
```

It's not producing the right results and I have no idea why. Could someone help me out please?

Comment: To make sure XML elements are not interpreted as HTML, wrap them in code blocks (eg., using backticks). Read the [FAQ] for details. Please also have a look at [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and provide  both well-formed example XML input, current output (and explain what's wrong with it) and expected output.

Comment: And you should go through your questions and mark those answers that solved your problem using the checkmark on the left (if there is an answer that did so). This not only shows future visitors how your problem was resolved, but also somewhat honors the effort of the answerer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the first problem is that your XQuery is syntactically incorrect. Something starting with a dollar sign `$` indicates a variable, whereas `//` is a path step. Combining a variable and path step like you did `//$Teacher` is incorrect. Hence, your compiler should already complain about that.

The next problem is that your logic is flawed. You say you want to get all students, but then you iterate over all teachers.

Additionally, your approach would fail, because students is most likely a set of all students, so if you search for `$students/@age` you get the set of *all* ages. Hence, if you do this twice (for another attribute such as `@name`, it is not guaranteed the name and age belong to the same person.

So, the following XQuery should work and return the expected results:

```
$students/student[exists(
  let $s := .
  for $t in $teachers[@name = $s/@name and @age < $s/@age]
  return $s
)]
```

This way, you get all students, where there is at least one teacher with the same name and a younger age.